# Oracle Cloud: load data in private endpoint Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

Actually i can reach and select my Database in private endpoint throughout a publc bastion server. Is there a best practise to load data from on Premise Database to Oracle Cloud Database in private endpoint? It would be enough for me to load data via Database Link. So my idea is to create a public autonmous database to load data from on Premise and in next step redirect data to private database. Then i create as described a database link which linked to my Autonmous Database:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/database-links-inbound.html#GUID-EB369724-29CE-452E-8EC1-2E0B33AE0A49

But using the DB-link (in SQL Developer) throws Error:

ORA-28860: Schwerwiegender SSL-Fehler
28860. 00000 -  "Fatal SSL error"
*Cause:    An error occurred during the SSL connection to the peer. It is likely
that this side sent data which the peer rejected.
*Action:   Enable tracing to determine the exact cause of this error.
Contact Oracle customer support if needed.

Do you have an idea why the error occurs or better suggestions to load Data in private endpoints?

Comment: consider: dumping your data to csv, uploading those files to the object store, then using dbms_cloud to load them back into your autonomous database tables

Comment: You need to describe your use case a bit more clear. Is this a one-time load? Are you envisioning building some pipeline?

While I think it's doable what you are asking for, it does not sound like the best architecture. Going through the object store, as Jeff said, sounds way more compelling.

Comment: Hello Hermann, yes i want daily building piplines which used for automatic daily load from Source Systems. I think Jeffs proposal sounds the best.